# BaseHTTPRequestHandler freezes while writing to self.wfile after installing Python 3.0

Tags: python, sockets

I'm starting to lose my head with this one.

I have a class that extends BaseHTTPRequestHandler. It works fine on
Python 2.5. And yesterday I was curious and decided to install Python
3.0 on my Mac (I followed this tutorial, to be sure I wasn't messing
things up: http://farmdev.com/thoughts/66/python-3-0-on-mac-os-x-alongside-2-6-2-5-etc-/
). I tried my application on Python 3.0 and the code just freezed on
this line:

```
self.wfile.write(f.read())
```

I searched and got to this bug http://bugs.python.org/issue3826. I
couldn't understand if there's already a fix for that. But, the
strangest thing was that, when I tried my application on 2.5, it
started freezing on the same spot! I then removed everything I
installed from 3.0, fixed the paths, and it still gives me the error.
I don't know what else to do.

The app works fine on 2.5, because I tried it on another computer.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could we close this question as "not relevant any longer"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, it seems to have been a weird setting between routers `(mac <-> router <-> router <-> ISP)` here at home.

Small files ( < 100kB ) were served with no problem at all, but larger files got stuck. I found it out after formatting my mac, and realized that it was still happening. I tried to remove on of the routers out of the way and it sure works now. The real reason that caused it, and why it worked before and suddently stopped working after (coincidently, for sure) installing Python 3.0 is still incognito for me.

Thanks for the readers.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest develop a simple page that would dump the version details of the perl environment and confirm that now you are back on 2.5. Mostly in such scenarios there are some environment entries or binaries that are left out.